# How to set Wails path for Go on Mac?

Tags: go, apache-age, wails

I'm trying to use Wails with Go on my Mac, but I'm having trouble setting the correct path. I have installed both Wails and Go, but when I try to build my Wails application using wails build, I get an error message saying "Go not found on path."

How do I set the correct path for Go so that Wails can find it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set follow these Guidelines:

```
devn@macbook-pro-2 ~ % wails doctor
zsh: command not found: wails
devn@macbook-pro-2 ~ % mkdir ~/go
mkdir: /Users/devn/go: File exists
devn@macbook-pro-2 ~ % export GOPATH=~/go 
devn@macbook-pro-2 ~ % go install github.com/wailsapp/wails/v2/cmd/wails@latest

devn@macbook-pro-2 ~ % export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin

devn@macbook-pro-2 ~ % ~/.bashrc
zsh: permission denied: /Users/devn/.bashrc
devn@macbook-pro-2 ~ % sudo ~/.bashrc
Password:
sudo: /Users/devn/.bashrc: command not found
devn@macbook-pro-2 ~ % sudo ~/.bash_profile
sudo: /Users/devn/.bash_profile: command not found
devn@macbook-pro-2 ~ % source ~/.bashrc
devn@macbook-pro-2 ~ % wails version
v2.4.1
 ♥   If Wails is useful to you or your company, please consider sponsoring the project:
https://github.com/sponsors/leaanthony
devn@macbook-pro-2 ~ %
```

Answer (score 2):

check if the wails is installed by this command:

`wails doctor`

if it's not installed you can install following this command:

```
go install github.com/wailsapp/wails/v2/cmd/wails@latest
```

so create a new Go workspace `mkdir ~/go` and set the env variable `export GOPATH=~/go`.

Add the go bin directory to your system PATH variable `export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin`. After this reload your shell profile `source ~/.bashrc`. Finally verify if the wails is installed and working following this command:

```
wails version
```